# How to make a recursive rule in boost spirit x3 in VS2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, boost-spirit-x3

I've written the following recursive rule in boost::spirit::x3 but it only seems to compile in g++/clang, not VS2017 (15.5.3):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>

namespace lex3
{
    namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

    x3::rule<struct foo_class> const foo = "foo";
    x3::rule<struct bar_class> const bar = "bar";

    auto bar_def = *((x3::char_ - "/*") - "*/") >> *(foo > *((x3::char_ - "/*") - "*/"));
    auto foo_def = "/*" > bar > "*/";

    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(foo)
    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(bar)
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::string input = "/* a /* nested */ comment */";
    auto f = input.begin();
    auto l = input.end();

    if (parse(f, l, lex3::foo) && (f == l))
        std::cout << "Parse success.\n";
    else
        std::cout << "Parse failure (remainder: " << std::string(f, l) << ").\n";

    return 0;
}
```

[Coliru link, g++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/003bd4243135f714)

[Coliru link, clang++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a1f99240d1ae9055)

How do I make this work in VS2017 (if possible)?

P.S: Platform Toolset is set to v141, ISO standard is set to C++17, boost version is 1.66.0

P.P.S: The compilation errors are as follows

```
error C2039: 'insert': is not a member of 'boost::spirit::x3::unused_type'
note: see declaration of 'boost::spirit::x3::unused_type'
error C2039: 'end': is not a member of 'boost::spirit::x3::unused_type'
note: see declaration of 'boost::spirit::x3::unused_type'
error C2039: 'begin': is not a member of 'boost::spirit::x3::unused_type'
note: see declaration of 'boost::spirit::x3::unused_type'
```

Comment: It's a bug in Spirit.  Here is the fix: https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/commit/ee4943d5891bdae0706fb616b908e3bf528e0dfa

Comment: That does seem to be the case. If you make that an answer I'll upvote/accept in the morning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I checked out the Boost.Spirit repository on GitHub because my local version was too old and noticed that your example compiles fine with the latest `develop` branch but not with the 1.66.0 release (also on Clang and GCC).  Bisecting the commit history revealed that this bug was fixed in

> [`ee4943d5891bdae0706fb616b908e3bf528e0dfa`](https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/commit/ee4943d5891bdae0706fb616b908e3bf528e0dfa)

You could either apply the patch from this commit to your installation or wait for the next release.