# How to parse CSV in C++ using Boost memory maps?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, memory-mapped-files, boost-spirit-qi

I have a really huge file with 17 million records in it.

Here is a sample of the file:

```
Actor Movie
1,2
2,2
3,1
4,3
2,3
```

I would want to skip the first line and start the parsing from second line onward. I am trying to create two things.
1. Movies to actors map
`vector<uint64_t> *movie_map = new vector<uint64_t>[1200000];`
2. Actors to movies map
`vector<uint64_t> *actor_movie_map = new vector<uint64_t>[2000000];`
I purposefully did not want a HashMap since it takes some time for computing hash. I tried to use Boost library. It reads the file(~250MB) in about 3 seconds, but a lot of time is consumed while creating the maps. In fact the time is worse than normal `getline()` way of reading the file. Here is my implementation so far.

```
using CsvField = boost::string_ref;
using CsvLine  = std::vector<CsvField>;
using CsvFile  = std::vector<CsvLine>;

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
struct CsvParser : qi::grammar<char const*, CsvFile()> {
    CsvParser() : CsvParser::base_type(lines)
    {
        using boost::phoenix::construct;
        using boost::phoenix::begin;
        using boost::phoenix::size;

        using namespace qi;

        field = raw [*~char_(",\r\n")] [ _val = construct<CsvField>(begin(_1), size(_1)) ];
        line  = field % ',';
        lines = line  % eol;
    }
  private:
    qi::rule<char const*, CsvField()> field;
    qi::rule<char const*, CsvLine()>  line;
    qi::rule<char const*, CsvFile()>  lines;
};

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source csv("playedin.csv");

    CsvFile parsed;
    parsed.reserve(18*1000*1000);
    if (qi::parse(csv.data(), csv.data() + csv.size(), CsvParser(), parsed))
    {
        using boost::lexical_cast;
        for(uint64_t i=1; i < parsed.size(); i++){
        auto& line = parsed[i];
        uint64_t sample = lexical_cast<uint64_t>(line[0]);
        movie_map[lexical_cast<uint64_t>(line[1])].push_back(lexical_cast<uint64_t>(line[0]));
        actor_movie_map[lexical_cast<uint64_t>(line[0])].push_back(lexical_cast<uint64_t>(line[1]));

        }
    }
}
```

I do not want to use the normal way of reading file because of the large size of the file. Please suggest a way of implementing this so that the whole file reading and preparing map for 17 million records should happen in less than 2-3 seconds.I understand that the expectation is little too much, but I am sure it is possible. I am really looking at the most efficient way of doing this.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is probably more related to Spirit than memory mapped files.

Answer (score 1):

- > vector *movie_map = new vector[1200000];

  ✍ Never use `new` or `delete` in modern c++
- > I purposefully did not want a HashMap since it takes some time for computing hash.

  Exactly how much time does calculating the hash take? I mean, chances are that a hash-map aren't the best choice here, but your reasoning is off. On may implementations `std::hash<>` of a 64 bit integer is a no-op (on a system where `size_t` is 64 bits)¹.

### But The Kicker Is:

You ... read all of the data into a `CsvFile` first (that's a vector of vectors of string_refs...) only to **then** convert to a map?!

This is ridiculous. Simply skip the middle man, you don't need it!

Mind you, spirit is a **parser generator**. It's ridiculous in every respect to parse the text first, only to use `lexical_cast` on the result.

### Demo

Here's a c++14 demo that cuts the middle man, using Boost Spirit X3 for good measure. I chose `flat_multimap` a bit randomly to make two points:

- your data structure is "like a" multi-map, perhaps even an adjacency list. What does your use-case require of it?
- there are (many) existing datastructures that have subtly varying performance characteristics

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/13bda74a9c41388e)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/container/flat_map.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_pair.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/mapped_file.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>

using Table  = boost::container::flat_multimap<uint64_t, uint64_t>;
using Record = Table::value_type;

namespace Parsing {
    using namespace boost::spirit::x3;

    auto const ignore_header_row 
        = !uint_ >> *(char_ - eol) >> eol;

    auto const record 
        = rule<struct _rl, Record> {"record"}
        = uint_ >> ',' >> uint_ >> eol;

    auto const file 
     // = rule<struct _file, Table> {"file"}
        = omit [*ignore_header_row] >> *record >> eoi;
}

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source mfs("playedin.csv");

    Table table;
    table.reserve(18*1000*1000);
    if (parse(mfs.begin(), mfs.end(), Parsing::file, table)) {
        std::cout << "Parsed " << table.size() << " records\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Parsed 5 records
```

> **Caveat** In latest boost versions there is a regression in X3 attribute handling, you will want to use the fix from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48393573/85371

### Benchmark + Query

Benchmarking predictably shows that inserting 17+million unsorted rows is not optimal [using the flat-map approach](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bfe1284f34b9cc75):

- 1,000,000 unsorted rows are read in ~4m39s,
- with the input sorted it takes only 0.113s to read those same rows [output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCsXp.png)

The obvious bottle neck is sorting while parsing. That's easily fixed: we don't need to sort while parsing. Just [sort it *after* parsing](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/748d1e798b8ef31d):

- all 17.4 million rows are now parsed and sorted in 1.922s, or 1.284s if presorted ([output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S999n.png) again)

### Benchmarked Code Listing

The final version **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/748d1e798b8ef31d)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/container/flat_map.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_pair.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/mapped_file.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/qi.hpp>

using Table  = boost::container::vector<std::pair<uint64_t, uint64_t> >;
using Record = Table::value_type;

namespace Parsing {
    using namespace boost::spirit::qi;
    using Iterator = char const*;

    static const rule<Iterator> ignore_header_row
        = !uint_ >> *(char_ - eol) >> eol;
    static const rule<Iterator, Record()> record 
        = uint_ >> ',' >> uint_ >> eol;

    static const rule<Iterator, Table()> file 
        = omit [*ignore_header_row] >> *record >> eoi;
}

Table parse_data(std::string const& fname) {
    boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source mfs(fname);

    Table table;
    table.reserve(18*1000*1000);
    if (!parse(mfs.begin(), mfs.end(), Parsing::file, table))
        throw std::runtime_error("Parse failed");

    sort(table.begin(), table.end());
    return table;
}

template <typename It> struct iterator_range {
    It b, e;
    iterator_range() = default;
    iterator_range(std::pair<It, It> p) : b(p.first), e(p.second) {}
    It begin() const { return b; }
    It end() const   { return e; }
};

struct by_actor {
    template <typename T, typename U>
    bool operator()(T const& a, U const& b) const { return actor(a) < actor(b); }
  private:
    static uint64_t actor(Record const& r) { return r.first; }
    static uint64_t actor(uint64_t i) { return i; }
};

#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Table const& table = parse_data("playedin.csv");

    auto query = [&table](uint64_t actor) { 
        return iterator_range<Table::const_iterator>(equal_range(table.begin(), table.end(), actor, by_actor{}));
    };

    for (auto actor : std::vector<std::string>{argv+1, argv+argc}) {
        std::cout << "Actor " << actor << " played in:";
        for (auto movie : query(std::stoull(actor)))
            std::cout << " " << movie.second;
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

---

¹ likewise, boost's `boost::hash<>` defers to `boost::hash_value(unsigned long long)` which is documented to return [`val` when `abs(val) <= std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/hash/reference.html#boost.hash_va_1_3_16_11_2_2_27_1).

Comment: I tried changing `using CsvField = boost::string_ref;` to `using CsvField = std::uint64_t;`, but it is giving me compilation errors. It would be great if you can host the whole program on your site. Thanks :)

Comment: Which site would that be? Anyhow, here's a [version that skips the middle-man and randomly chose `boost::container::flat_multimap<>`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/13bda74a9c41388e) because you might not know it exists. I'll update my answer. If you include the `playedin.csv` file somewhere I'll do some benchmarking (likely `std::multimap` vs. `flat_multimap`, maybe vs. `boost::adjacency_list` or something - your question spells of a graph problem)

Comment: Thank you very much! The file can be downloaded at [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HftwiuS9ljH6t3ZGFktiDTGnYURAqYZK/view). I tried to run the code on my local. It is giving me compilation errors even after applying the fix from git.

Comment: Testing with that large file and this [slightly extended test program](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e7fa9e984e401b5d) prints [query results in 1.894s](https://i.imgur.com/ZzW36fI.png). Parsing [_alone_](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b7e274d9f745b68e) takes [0.819s](https://i.imgur.com/4u9dFyl.png).

Comment: Here's a [version using just C++11](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/748d1e798b8ef31d) (Boost Spirit Qi) that runs [in the same amount of time](https://i.imgur.com/oDMlULa.png). It compiles fine [on MSVC](http://rextester.com/UPLL59025) (of course it doesn't run correctly because there's no input file there)

Comment: Added some benchmark results/analysis to the answer.

Comment: The benchmark scores look really promising. However, the program returns a Table which is pairs of actors and movies in each row which is sort of useless. The whole point of this was to return two maps. `vector<uint64_t> *movie_to_actor_map = new vector<uint64_t>[1200000];
vector<uint64_t> *actor_to_movie_map = new vector<uint64_t>[2000000];`.
This will give me the list of movies each actor has played in and also the list of actors of each movie. I wanted to create these maps while parsing itself so I save some time in transferring.

Comment: If you have noticed in my implementation, I have used `movie_to_actor_map[movie].push_back(actor);
 actor_to_movie_map[actor].push_back(movie));` where `actor` and `movie` are the first and second columns in the dataset respectively. This allows me to fetch either actors played in a particular movie or movies in which actor has acted by using `[]` indexing. I will store Actor n's movies in the nth index. This way my lookups will be easy and fast ;) Could you please make these last changes if you don't mind? :)

Comment: Here is how I have successfully implemented this without memory maps. File reading, parsing, and finding Bacon number for 50 test cases(called on threads) using Bidirectional BFS works in ~ 13 seconds.
`std::ifstream file(lPath);    
 string dummyline;
 std::getline(file,dummyline);
 
int64_t fir,sec;
 while(file >> fir 
 && file.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), ',')
 && file >> sec){
       movie_to_actor_map[sec].push_back(fir);
       actor_to_movie_map[fir].push_back(sec);
}
`

Comment: Haha. So I was exactly right that I smelled a graph problem. The multimap is _exactly_ like an adjacency-list representation of that, so my sample did already do the building while parsing.

Comment: Which id is Bacon? If you give it on the command line here, this [test program](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1198bb1321245872) calculates the Bacon rank for **every** other movie/actor in the dataset in 12.7s here. As a demo, [it shows the most remote relation (which usually is an actor, but could be a movie), with the connecting path](https://i.imgur.com/iGW7A9e.png). For fun I used Boost Graph this time around.

Comment: Please find my implementation on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/73f1dd5f531b2f57). Dijkstra's algorithm is only as good as BFS when the graph is unweighted. I am using Bidirectional BFS which is way faster. Also, I have tweaked the algorithm so it uses two of the maps that I have come up with. My [benchmark](https://imgur.com/AaAYSjh) on bigger dataset. Please note, this is for TWO test cases ;) Using memory maps to read the file will only make it better. Please please implement that?

Comment: Can you post that at [CodeReview.SE]?

Comment: Please find the code [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/186530/program-to-parse-csv-and-use-bidirectional-bfs-to-find-the-shortest-degree-of-co)

Answer (score 0):

A few thoughts:

- Lexical_cast tends to be slow.
- Memory mapping the file does not help sequential access.  It might even be worse than regular reading-by-chunks.
- An array of vectors is inefficient if the vectors are small.  Each vector consumes at least three pointers worth of space when it is empty.  You'd be better off with a different container, like `std::unordered_map`.

Comment: Do you recommend implementing thread on Memory mapping? Would that be better? If yes, do you have any resources? 
I have tried with `std::unordered_map`. This gave better result.

Comment: "Implementing thread on Memory mapping?" It sounds a bit like you're regurgitating words you heard. If unodered_map gave good results, why not use it? There's little use in finding complicated optimizations that you don't understand, IMO

Comment: @sehe
I meant, if I should consider having threads to parse/read the memory mapped file. If yes, would that improve the performance?

Comment: @sehe unordered maps gave worse results than array of vectors. That is why I stuck to this

Comment: @Harshita: I don't think threading is going to help you at all.  Your code is already overly complex relative to an optimized version.