# Unhelpful compiler errors in x3 grammar

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

The following Spirit x3 grammar for a simple robot command language generates compiler errors in Windows Visual Studio 17. For this project, I am required to compile with the warning level to 4 (/W4) and treat warnings as errors (/WX).

> Warning   C4127   conditional expression is
>   constant  SpiritTest  e:\data\boost\boost_1_65_1\boost\spirit\home\x3\char\detail\cast_char.hpp   29
>   Error C2039   'insert': is not a member of
>   'boost::spirit::x3::unused_type'  SpiritTest  e:\data\boost\boost_1_65_1\boost\spirit\home\x3\core\detail\parse_into_container.hpp    259  Error  C2039   'end': is not a member of
>   'boost::spirit::x3::unused_type'  SpiritTest  e:\data\boost\boost_1_65_1\boost\spirit\home\x3\core\detail\parse_into_container.hpp    259  Error  C2039   'empty': is not a member of
>   'boost::spirit::x3::unused_type'  SpiritTest  e:\data\boost\boost_1_65_1\boost\spirit\home\x3\core\detail\parse_into_container.hpp    254  Error  C2039   'begin': is not a member of
>   'boost::spirit::x3::unused_type'  SpiritTest  e:\data\boost\boost_1_65_1\boost\spirit\home\x3\core\detail\parse_into_container.hpp    259

Clearly, something is wrong with my grammar, but the error messages are completely unhelpful. I have found that if I remove the Kleene star in the last line of the grammar (*parameter to just parameter) the errors disappear, but then I get lots of warnings like this:

> Warning   C4459   declaration of 'digit' hides global
>   declaration   SpiritTest  e:\data\boost\boost_1_65_1\boost\spirit\home\x3\support\numeric_utils\detail\extract_int.hpp    174
>   Warning C4127   conditional expression is constant  SpiritTest  e:\data\boost\boost_1_65_1\boost\spirit\home\x3\char\detail\cast_char.hpp   29

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

//
// Grammar for simple command language
//

namespace scl
    {
    using boost::spirit::x3::char_;
    using boost::spirit::x3::double_;
    using boost::spirit::x3::int_;
    using boost::spirit::x3::lexeme;
    using boost::spirit::x3::lit;
    using boost::spirit::x3::no_case;

    auto    valid_identifier_chars = char_ ("a-zA-Z_");
    auto    quoted_string = '"' >> *(lexeme [~char_ ('"')]) >> '"';
    auto    keyword_value_chars = char_ ("a-zA-Z0-9$_.");

    auto    qual = lexeme [!(no_case [lit ("no")]) >> +valid_identifier_chars] >> -('=' >> (quoted_string | int_ | double_ | +keyword_value_chars));
    auto    neg_qual = lexeme [no_case [lit ("no")] >> +valid_identifier_chars];
    auto    qualifier = lexeme ['/' >> (qual | neg_qual)];

    auto    verb = +valid_identifier_chars >> *qualifier;
    auto    parameter = +keyword_value_chars >> *qualifier;
    auto    command = verb >> *parameter;
    };  // End namespace scl

using namespace std;                                    // Must be after Boost stuff!

int
main ()

{
vector <string> input = 
    {
    "show/out=\"somefile.txt\" motors/all cameras/full",
    "start/speed=5 motors arm1 arm2/speed=2.5/track arm3",
    "rotate camera1/notrack/axis=y/angle=45"
    };

    //
    // Parse each of the strings in the input vector
    //

    for (string str : input)
        {
        auto    b = str.begin ();
        auto    e = str.end ();


        cout << "Parsing: " << str << endl;
        x3::phrase_parse (b, e, scl::command, x3::space);

        if (b != e)
            {
            cout << "Error, only parsed to position: " << b - str.begin () << endl;
            }

        }   // End for

    return 0;
}                           // End main
```

Comment: Let me know if the dupe isn't a dupe. Most likely it is. You could "fix" it by supplying a compatible attribute instead of course

Comment: @sehe, I don't see how it is recursive. A verb can have zero or more qualifiers, and the verb can have zero or more parameters, with each parameter having zero or more qualifiers

Comment: That question had nothing to do with recursive rules - it just had that in the title because it was what triggered the library bug.

Comment: I'll work it out later tonight. Midway a rehearsal here

Comment: There. It's exactly a duplicate as I mentioned, but I fleshed out an explanation. I made the explanation more worthwhile by reviewing the grammar and completing it with a demonstration Ast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a regression since Boost 1.65 that causes problems with some rules that potentially propagate into container type attributes.

They dispatch to the wrong overload when instantiated without an actual bound attribute. When this happens there is a "mock" attribute type called `unused_type`. The errors you are seeing indicate that `unused_type` is being treated as if it were a concrete attribute type, and clearly that won't fly.

The regression was fixed in https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/commit/ee4943d5891bdae0706fb616b908e3bf528e0dfa

You can see that it's a regression by compiling with Boost 1.64:

- Boost 1.64 compiles it *fine* [GCC 
  and Clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/8NVsIuk4QqMPUdZs)
- Boost 1.65 breaks it [GCC](https://wandbox.org/permlink/5Z5KwqpAu2RMiz2z) and [Clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/WalsLHbeyTlC5mHE) again

Now, latest develop is supposed to fix it, but you can simply copy the patched file, [even just the 7-line patch](https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/commit/ee4943d5891bdae0706fb616b908e3bf528e0dfa#diff-2b82341b4caa57a2a0c6bc9a616a1e1a).

> All of the above was already available when I linked the duplicate question [How to make a recursive rule in boost spirit x3 in VS2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48392993/how-to-make-a-recursive-rule-in-boost-spirit-x3-in-vs2017), which highlights the same regression

### Review

- `using namespace std; // Must be after Boost stuff!`

  Actually, it probably needs to be nowhere unless very locally scoped, where you can see the impact of any potential name colisions.
- Consider encapsulating the skipper, since it's likely logically part of your grammar spec, not something to be overridden by the caller.
- This is a bug:

  ```
  auto quoted_string = '"' >> *(lexeme[~char_('"')]) >> '"';
  ```

  You probably meant to assert the whole literal is lexeme, not individual characters (that's... moot because whitespace would never hit the parser anyways, because of the skipper).

  ```
  auto quoted_string = lexeme['"' >> *~char_('"') >> '"'];
  ```
- Likewise, you might have intended `+keyword_value_chars` to be lexeme, because right now `one=two three four` would parse the "qualifier" `one` with a "keyword value" of `onethreefour`, not `one three four`¹
- `x3::space` skips embedded newlines, if that's not the intent, use `x3::blank`
- Since PEG grammars are parsed left-to-right *greedy*, you can order the `qualifier` production and do without the `!(no_case["no"])` lookahead assertion. That not only removes duplication but also makes the grammar simpler and more efficient:

  ```
  auto qual      = lexeme[+valid_identifier_chars] >>
      -('=' >> (quoted_string | int_ | double_ | +keyword_value_chars)); // TODO lexeme
  auto neg_qual  = lexeme[no_case["no"] >> +valid_identifier_chars];
  auto qualifier = lexeme['/' >> (neg_qual | qual)];
  ```

  > ¹ **Note** (Post-Scriptum) now that we notice `qualifier` is, itself, already a lexeme, there's no need to `lexeme[]` things inside (unless, of course they're reused in contexts with skippers).
  >
  > However, this also gives rise to the question whether whitespace around the `=` operator should be accepted (currently, it is not), or whether qualifiers can be separated with whitespace (like `id /a /b`; currently they can).
- Perhaps `verb` needed some `lexemes[]` as well (unless you really *did* want to parse `"one two three"` as a verb)
- If `no` prefix for negative qualifiers, then *maybe* the identifier itself is, too? This could simplify the grammar
- The ordering of `int_` and `double_` makes it so that most doubles are mis-parsed as `int` before they could ever be recognized. Consider something more explicit like `x3::strict_real_policies<double>>{} | int_`
- If you're parsing quoted constructs, perhaps you want to recognize escapes too (`'\"'` and `'\\'` for example):

  ```
  auto quoted_string = lexeme['"' >> *('\\' >> char_ | ~char_('"')) >> '"'];
  ```
- If you have a need for "keyword values" consider listing known values in `x3::symbols<>`. This can also be used to parse directly into an enum type.

Here's a version that parses into AST types and prints it back for demonstration purposes:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/807ca5194f0c4e05)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

namespace Ast {
    struct Keyword : std::string { // needs to be strong-typed to distinguish from quoted values
        using std::string::string;
        using std::string::operator=;
    };

    struct Nil {};
    using Value = boost::variant<Nil, std::string, int, double, Keyword>;

    struct Qualifier {
        enum Kind { positive, negative } kind;
        std::string identifier;
        Value       value;
    };

    struct Param {
        Keyword                keyword;
        std::vector<Qualifier> qualifiers;
    };

    struct Command {
        std::string            verb;
        std::vector<Qualifier> qualifiers;
        std::vector<Param>     params;
    };
}

#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Ast::Qualifier, kind, identifier, value)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Ast::Param, keyword, qualifiers)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Ast::Command, verb, qualifiers, params)

#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;
namespace scl {
    //
    // Grammar for simple command language
    //
    using x3::char_;
    using x3::int_;
    using x3::lexeme;
    using x3::no_case;

    // lexeme tokens
    auto keyword       = x3::rule<struct _keyword, Ast::Keyword> { "keyword" }
                       = lexeme [ +char_("a-zA-Z0-9$_.") ];
    auto identifier    = lexeme [ +char_("a-zA-Z_") ];
    auto quoted_string = lexeme['"' >> *('\\' >> x3::char_ | ~x3::char_('"')) >> '"'];

    auto value
        = quoted_string
        | x3::real_parser<double, x3::strict_real_policies<double>>{}
        | x3::int_
        | keyword;

    auto qual
        = x3::attr(Ast::Qualifier::positive) >> identifier >> -('=' >> value);
    auto neg_qual
        = x3::attr(Ast::Qualifier::negative) >> lexeme[no_case["no"] >> identifier] >> x3::attr(Ast::Nil{}); // never a value
    auto qualifier 
        = lexeme['/' >> (neg_qual | qual)];

    auto verb      
        = identifier;

    auto parameter = x3::rule<struct _parameter, Ast::Param> {"parameter"}
        = keyword >> *qualifier;

    auto command = x3::rule<struct _command, Ast::Command> {"command"} 
        = x3::skip(x3::space) [ verb >> *qualifier >> *parameter ];

} // End namespace scl

// For Demo, Debug: printing the Ast types back
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

namespace Ast {
    static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Value const& v) {
        struct {
            std::ostream& _os;
            void operator()(std::string const& s) const { _os << std::quoted(s); }
            void operator()(int i)                const { _os << i; } 
            void operator()(double d)             const { _os << d; } 
            void operator()(Keyword const& kwv)   const { _os << kwv; } 
            void operator()(Nil)                  const { }
        } vis{os};

        boost::apply_visitor(vis, v);
        return os;
    }

    static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Qualifier const& q) {
        os << "/" << (q.kind==Qualifier::negative?"no":"") << q.identifier;
        if (q.value.which())
           os << "=" << q.value;
        return os;
    }

    static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, std::vector<Qualifier> const& qualifiers) {
        for (auto& qualifier : qualifiers)
            os << qualifier;
        return os;
    }

    static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Param const& p) {
        return os << p.keyword << p.qualifiers;
    }

    static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Command const& cmd) {
        os << cmd.verb << cmd.qualifiers;
        for (auto& param : cmd.params)         os << " " << param;
        return os;
    }
}

int main() {
    for (std::string const str : {
            "show/out=\"somefile.txt\" motors/all cameras/full",
            "start/speed=5 motors arm1 arm2/speed=2.5/track arm3",
            "rotate camera1/notrack/axis=y/angle=45",
        })
    {
        auto b = str.begin(), e = str.end();

        Ast::Command cmd;
        bool ok = parse(b, e, scl::command, cmd);
        std::cout << (ok?"OK":"FAIL") << '\t' << std::quoted(str) << '\n';

        if (ok) {
            std::cout << " -- Full AST: " << cmd << "\n";
            std::cout << " -- Verb+Qualifiers: " << cmd.verb << cmd.qualifiers << "\n";
            for (auto& param : cmd.params)
                std::cout << "     -- Param+Qualifiers: " << param << "\n";
        }

        if (b != e) {
            std::cout << " -- Remaining unparsed: " << std::quoted(std::string(b,e)) << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Prints

```
OK  "show/out=\"somefile.txt\" motors/all cameras/full"
 -- Full AST: show/out="somefile.txt" motors/all cameras/full
 -- Verb+Qualifiers: show/out="somefile.txt"
     -- Param+Qualifiers: motors/all
     -- Param+Qualifiers: cameras/full
OK  "start/speed=5 motors arm1 arm2/speed=2.5/track arm3"
 -- Full AST: start/speed=5 motors arm1 arm2/speed=2.5/track arm3
 -- Verb+Qualifiers: start/speed=5
     -- Param+Qualifiers: motors
     -- Param+Qualifiers: arm1
     -- Param+Qualifiers: arm2/speed=2.5/track
     -- Param+Qualifiers: arm3
OK  "rotate camera1/notrack/axis=y/angle=45"
 -- Full AST: rotate camera1/notrack/axis=y/angle=45
 -- Verb+Qualifiers: rotate
     -- Param+Qualifiers: camera1/notrack/axis=y/angle=45
```

> For completeness
>
> - Demo also [Live On MSVC (Rextester)](http://rextester.com/QTI48245) - note that RexTester uses Boost 1.60
> - Coliru uses Boost 1.66 **but** the problem doesn't manifest itself because now, there are concrete attribute values bound to parsers

Comment: Wow, that is an awesome response. Thank you very much for taking the time to teach me how to do this! Clearly, my understanding of x3 is rudimentary, but it is nice to know that it wasn't all my fault. I was planning on using x3::symbol for the Verbs, Qualifiers, and Keywords but I just wanted to get a basic parser working. I also want to implement abbreviations (for V, Q, K). Is using x3::symbol the best way to do that? Why does an input of "run /q1 /q2 p1 /q3 = abc p2" fail to parse properly? The identifier rule doesn't contain a '/', so why doesn't verb stop matching at the '/'?

Comment: "/q3 = abc" shouldn't parse because `q3` is not a valid identifier. Besides, like I mentioned in the **Note** above: whitespace around `=` is currently not accepted.

Comment: Re.: _"The identifier rule doesn't contain a '/', so why doesn't verb stop matching at the '/'?"_ - huh, where do you see that problem? Look closely at the actual output: [I don't think it says anything like you expect it to say](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/72e8148cd8534729)

Comment: Talking to you is like talking to a Zen Master. Everything you say is absolutely correct, but my own preconceptions and limited knowledge of the subject keeps from understanding right away ;-)
So, what is the best way to implement abbreviations of verbs, qualifiers, and keywords? My thought was to provide a list of valid strings and then have a routine generate the abbreviations and put them into x3::symbol

Comment: @Brian that's seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44261883/85371
Tangentially related is [this post about generating autocompletions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47354226/85371).